# Single sign on (SSO): does user need to sign into each site once to establish same identity?

Tags: single-sign-on

Single sign on (SSO): does a user need to sign into each site once to establish same identity? e.g.

1. open [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) the first time and sign in using his username/password.
2. open [www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com) the first time. Does the same user needs to sign into this site using the same username/password?

After authentication, the user establish the same identity for the example1.com and example2.com. Is cookie used to remember user identity?